# Using JQuery to cancel my singleline edit in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, reload

I am having trouble with using jquery to cancel and revert back to the Index partial view.

So here is what I am wanting my function to do.  If I add a row and decide that I want to cancel adding the row, it needs to go back to the original partial view.  What happens is that it keeps the added row on the screen once the function for canceling has been executed and I just manually refresh the screen. I don't want to do a location.reload(true), because that will refresh the entire page, I just want it to refresh the actual partial view.

Thank you in advanced for fresh eyes, I have been looking at this forever it seems, and i know I am missing something.

Function:

```
function cancelThis(element) {
var attendeeuserID = $(element).parents().find('.attendee-stored-  id').attr('data-value');
getCustomerByID(attendeeuserID, element);
}
function getCustomerByID(id, element) {
GetByID("UserCatalogView/Cancel", id, element);
}
function replaceAttendeeRow(result, element) {
$(element).closest('tr').replaceWith(result);
}
function GetByID(url, id, callback, param1) {

$.ajax({
    url: "../../" + url + "/" + id,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        if (callback != null && callback != undefined) {
            callback(result);
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        if (result.responseText != '') {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }
        else {
            alert("An error occurred while processing results.  Please consult an administrator.");
        }
    }
})
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Cancel (Guid id) //not using this controller at the moment.  Just using the window.location to cancel out. 
    {
        CatalogAttendeeModel model = new CatalogAttendeeModel();
        model.getAttendeesListByID(id);
        var catalog = from ca in db.Catalog_Attendee
                      join a in db.Attendees on ca.AttendeeID equals a.AttendeeID
                      where ca.AttendeeID == id
                      select ca;
        foreach (var item in catalog)
        {
            if (item.IsActive == null)
            {
                item.IsActive = true;
            }
        }
        return PartialView("Index", model);   
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@{
<tr>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("CatalogEdit")</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("StudyRoleEdit")</td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(item => item.usercatalogs.IsAdmin.Value)</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.usercatalogs.IsTrainingDocPrinted, new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "True" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "False" } }, new { style = "width:50px" })</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.usercatalogs.PIName, new { @class = "texbox", style = "width:70px" })</td>
    <td><img class="savecatalog" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="saveEdit(this)" title="Save" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/save.png")" />
        <img onclick="cancelThis(this)" style="cursor:pointer"    title="Cancel" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/cancel.png")" />      
</td>  
</tr>    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want to reset the controls back to the original default value?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, once it's updated, I want it to just basically refresh the partial view to show added row. So at the end of the return view shows the added row. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really :). You last comment says _once it's updated_ but you question talks about cancelling it. Not really sure what your wanting to do, but you can reset inputs to their default value using the `defaultValue` property of the input, or you can just remove the row using `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered using the toggle() method in javascript to toggle back and forth between inline views.  It works great. So for example in my partial view, I can wrap my edit view in a div and only expose it when I hit edit, it will display the edit view and hide the index view.  Then if I hit cancel, it will hide the edit view and unhide the index view just based on the onclick.